# How to find max and min of a dyanamic cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I wish to have 3 cells in excel.

One is dynamic and max and min cell.

So whenever the dynamic value goes to max, the max cell should be updated, else the max value should hold the previous highest value.

Similarly for min as well.

Comment: If your "dynamic cell" is actually a list and you are just entering new values underneath of each other all in the same column (so you can see a history of the values), then this is really easy, max value would just be `=MAX(A:A)` and min value would just be `=MIN(A:A)`.  If you mean the "dynamic cell" is always the same cell, just getting a new value entered into it and overwriting the previous value (so there is no history of values), then this would require VBA, specifically the [Worksheet_Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx).

Comment: Its the latter one, where the dynamic cell gets overwritten every time data gets refreshed. You have mentioned using VBA and more specifically using Worksheet_change event, could you tell me how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

VBA = Visual Basic for Applications.  To access it, open Excel and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.  In the Visual Basic Editor (VBE), double click on the sheet name that will have the dynamic cell.  In this example, it is just Sheet1.  After double-clicking on that sheet name, a code window will open on the right hand side.  At the top of the code window, use the two drop downs select Worksheet (in order to tell it you want a worksheet event) and then Change (to tell it you want the Worksheet_Change event.  It will auto create a line with `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` and will look something like this:

[image]

Then just copy this code and paste it in between the `Private Sub...` and `End Sub` lines so that it matches the picture:

```
Dim rDynamic As Range
Dim rMax As Range
Dim rMin As Range

Set rDynamic = Me.Range("A1")
Set rMax = Me.Range("B1")
Set rMin = Me.Range("C1")

If Not Intersect(Target, rDynamic) Is Nothing Then
    If rDynamic.Value < rMin.Value Then rMin.Value = rDynamic.Value
    If rDynamic.Value > rMax.Value Then rMax.Value = rDynamic.Value
End If
```

And test it out.  To save the workbook, you'll need to use the .xlsm file format, and you will also need to enable macros (Excel should prompt you to enable or disable macros after saving, closing, and reopening the workbook).