# How to keep lower values greater than zero in dynamic cells from RTD link?

Tags: excel

During 15 minutes of premarket, I would like to capture Min Values/Price of some stocks from Column B to Column F.

The values in column B come from the RTD link.

My formula to capture Min Values is

```
=IF(F4<=0;10000;AGGREGAte(5;6;B3;F4))
```

This works fine for 15 minutes after this time the values in column B are reset to Zero and I lose all information in column F.See picture below.

How to tell Excel: "If the value equal zero to keep the previous one higher than zero for each cell" ?

[MIN VALUES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sMJN.png)

Comment: I cannot see what you want to achieve based on the formula and the picture provided. You may want to clarify your question further, e.g. provide a sample data set with the desired outcome.

Comment: @TerryW OP should definitely clarify but I think they have a stock market service that pumps data to Excel periodically and want the formula to store and evaluate against the result from the last update. Leonardo - if that's accurate it's not possible with Excel alone, you will need a VBA solution.

Comment: Also, welcome to SO and please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: TerryW, I think Absinthe completed with more accurately what I want, is a RTD link that pumps data on Excel. I was thinking in a simple VBA like copypaste special during this period of time (15min) although I can lose some data when the premarket is extended for some stocks. Our colleague @tigeravatar created the code at the link below but I don't know if is possible to use the condition IF on it to keep values greater than zero, I don't have enough knowledge to try to modify this code. Tks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025061/how-to-find-max-and-min-of-a-dyanamic-cell-in-excel