# Max Min of dynamic cell not updating when worksheet/workbook in background

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

[How to find max and min of a dyanamic cell in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025061/how-to-find-max-and-min-of-a-dyanamic-cell-in-excel)
Hi all, with regard to the above vba code, I tried the code but the max/min cell only updates if I click on the dynamic cell and then click away. If the workbook is not active and is in the background while I work on other programs,the min/max cells wouldn't update. How do I fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` won't fire on a recalculation, so if your cells have formulas you'd need to use the `Calculate` event

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a regular formula, but requires Iterative Calculation to be enabled.

This is set under Options/Formulas

[image]

With this set, The `Max` formula should reference the cell(s) you want to monitor, and itself.

Eg if your `Max` is in `D3` in `Sheet1` and is monitoring `B3` on `Sheet2` then use

```
=MAX(Sheet2!B3,D3)
```

Note: stored Max value **will** survive the workbook being closed and reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Thic can be achieved with a volitile `UDF`, using a `Static` variable to remember the last Max value

```vb
Function MyMax(r As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile True
    Static LastMax As Variant
    Dim NewMax As Variant
    NewMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
    If NewMax > LastMax Then
        LastMax = NewMax
    End If
    MyMax = LastMax
End Function
```

Note:

1. stored Max value **won't** survive the workbook being closed and reopened.  To achieve that you'd need to store the value somewhere else, eg in an out of the way cell
2. This formula only stores **one** Max value.  If you want to use the formula >1 times in your workbook, each with its own Max, you'll need to store each Max seperately, perhaps in a Collection