# Save lowest value if dynamically new value is lower than previous value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I try to save the lowest value in a price overview, to keep track on price development. So basically, the value from A2 should be stored in cell C2, if the value is lower than the prior observed value. When a new lowest price is detected, this should be the new referenced value until there is an even lower price. So D2 needs to be adjusted whenever a new lowest price is found.

**So here is an example:** The price in A2 has fallen to 250$. When I enter the new price in A2, it is lower than the last price observed in D2 and the new lowest value in C2 will be 250. Now a few days later, the price increases to 260 (change in A2) - this is still lower than D2, hence the new lowest price is 260, what is actually wrong, because 250 was the lowest observed price.

[image]

I was hoping there is a way of keeping track with the price development, without changing the lowest observed value manually, but probably it's not possible, cause I can't store the older value without a circle independence.

However, I am not an expert in Excel - If somebody could solve that task, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: How about using the formula: 
D3 = MIN(C2, D2)

Comment: Generally, this is easily achievable. However, I have two questions: (i) your data is currently not soreted but I assume that it is important to keep the date component, (ii) does last value in column D refer to the same value as column A? Or what does it refer to? Or put differently, is it enough to have always the lowest value in column C?

Comment: I added an example in my description, which hopefully clarifies my issue (and your question)

Comment: Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72821492) can be used to achieve this

Comment: Thank you for the reference - As far as I see, I need to apply VBA to solve it. I didn't get it running with iterative calculation...

Comment: I think I finally found my solution (see answer below)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used the [iterative calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72821492) as recommended by [chris neilsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen). The resulting table with formulas looks as follows (translate "WENN" with "IF")

[image]

So it just tracks price steps downward but not upward. Probably not the most sophisticated way of tracking it, but sufficient for my case. Result:

[image]